# Having problems while creating a text editor using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, syntax

So hello everybody.
I recently had a problem which I tried to use python included file functions and stuff
i tried making a text editor which was when i encountered a problem

i tried to make the txteditor like this:

```
one = input()
two = input()
three = input()
four = input()
five = input()
six = input()
seven = input()
eight = input()
nine = input()
ten = input()
f= open("guru99.txt","w+")
for i in range(10):
     f.write(one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten)
f.close()
```

but it give the error :
f.write(one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten)
TypeError: TextIOWrapper.write() takes exactly one argument (10 given)
can aanybody help with this?
[image: here is the pic]

Comment: Looking at your code, I think that a text editor might be "a bit" too far fetched for your current level. Check https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/. As for your question, instead of having 10 individual variables, use a list (and write each of its elements in the file one at a time).

Comment: yeah i know my coding is not nearly efficient
just doing this for a fun project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing in each number as a separate [argument](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/function-argument) to `f.write()`, except that function only expects a single parameter.

You can do this by first joining all your inputs into a single variable, such as a string, and then passing that in. This is called [concatenation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/python-string-concatenation):

```
joinedInputs = one + two + three + four + ... + ten
f.write(joinedInputs)
```

However, this is a somewhat inefficient way of doing it, and you may want to research something like a [list](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp):

```
inputs = []
for i in range(10):
    userInput = input()
    inputs.append(userInput)
```

Then you can simply loop over all of them and join them to a single string, which can be done [a few ways](https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/python-tutorial/list-to-string-in-python), for example by looping over each element in the list and concatenating it as above.